# Converting Informix 'Perform' screens to a Windows-based application

Tags: informix

For the past several years we have slowly built an Access-based front end to access our  InformixSE database (unix). Our Sun server will be shut down in a couple of months and I'm looking for a relatively inexpensive solution for porting over the remainder of our old ".per" screens to a Windows-based solution. And even for the screens that have been reprogrammed, there's nothing that beats being able to query any field on the screen like you could with those simple-to-get-up-and-running Informix "Perform" screens.

Does anyone have experience with a solution?

Answer (score 1):

So why do away with the .per screens?.. Besides Aubit, take a look at 4J's [www.4js.com](http://www.4js.com)   .. or keep your ISQL Perform screens running on a VM like I have. (see perform video-demo at [www.frankcomputer.com](http://www.frankcomputer.com)).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Aubit4GL](http://aubit4gl.com/).